# Searching for Outlook emails with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, search, outlook

I've got a problem to search emails in Outlook.

This works :

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$e=$Outlook.AdvancedSearch("Inbox","urn:schemas:httpmail:subject='RECHERCHE QUI MARCHE'",$False,'test')
$e.results
```

Gives me the result OK.

But if I change the scope, it does not work.

```
PS C:\Users\etarai> $e=$Outlook.AdvancedSearch('\\xx@xx.com\Éléments supprimés',"urn:schemas:httpmail:subject='RECHERCHE QUI MARCHE'",$False,'test')
```

where '\\xx@xx.com\Éléments supprimés' is the FolderPath.
In msdn, scope should be a string with folderpath

> Scope Type: System.String
>
> The scope of the search. For example, the folder path of a folder. It
>   is recommended that the folder path is enclosed within single quotes.
>   Otherwise, the search might not return correct results if the folder
>   path contains special characters including Unicode characters. To
>   specify multiple folder paths, enclose each folder path in single
>   quotes and separate the single quoted folder paths with a comma.

How can I search in deleted emails, sent emails or in archives?
Have you got a solution to find a scope? When I try to put folderpath in scope, it does not work.

Other question, is it possible to see when research is complete?

Comment: Hi, have you tried with `'Éléments supprimés'` or `'Deleted Items'` as scope value?

Comment: It works with both [ PS C:\Users\etarai> $e=$Outlook.AdvancedSearch("'Éléments supprimés'","urn:schemas:httpmail:subject='RECHERCHE QUI MARC
E'",$False,'test')] and PS C:\Users\etarai> $e=$Outlook.AdvancedSearch("'Deleted Items'","urn:schemas:httpmail:subject='RECHERCHE QUI MARC
E'",$False,'test'). Now how can i search into archives pst files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whouaaaa i found THE answer!!
Thanks for your hint sodawillow!

For scope with folderpath
double quote AND single quote :

"'\xx@xx.com\deleted items'". Can be used with archives in pst files :)

Answer (score 1):

Works like a "-match"
Be carefull and test occurences, * is not interpreted

$Term  = 'Test'
$Scope = 'Inbox'

$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Emails  = $Outlook.AdvancedSearch( $Scope, "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%$Term%'", $true )

Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

$Emails.Results | Select-Object -Property Subject